# Vertically align :after pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move an :after pesudo element to come at the end of a div, sort of like a footer.

```
<div class="box">
    Some content here
</div>

.box {
     height: 60vh;
}

.box:after {
     content: "";
     vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

However, the pseudo content is always placed imediately after "Some content here", rather than as a footer for the .box... any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use position property to put `:after` like a footer:

```
.box {
    height: 60vh;
    border: 1px #AAA solid;
    position: relative;     // <-- relative
}
.box:after {
    content: "test";
    position: absolute;    // <-- absolute
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #DDD;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oc45nyux/

Comment: This will remove the pseudo element from normal document flow and could cause overlap with other content, unless taken care of carefully.

Comment: Nice one, I put position relative on the box.

Comment: @Arbel Everything should be treated carefully. But positioning is probably the only cross-browser way to achieve this task.

Comment: @Arbel Overlapping could be solved by adding a `padding-bottom` and `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `.box`; The pseudo-element should have an explicit height though. Also `height: 60vh;` should be changed to `min-height: 60vh;`.

Comment: @HashemQolami could you explain what these two properties are doing please?

Comment: @nwb `padding-bottom` would act as a spacer/placeholder at the bottom of the box; However it would increase the computed height of the box. In order to calculate the height of the box including padding, you could give `box-sizing: border-box` to the element. Also using `min-height` allows the element to grow according to its contents.

Comment: @HashemQolami so the box height also includes the pseudo element? and the pseudo element would be placed on top of the padding due to it being positioned with absolute? then if the box content overflows the box you set the height to min-height and allow it to grow to fit?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `display: block;` to `:after` and remove `vertical-align: bottom;`

```
.box:after {
     display: block;
     content: " ";
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but this doesn't seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/oc45nyux/1/

Comment: "test" is showing under (or on a new line block) after "Some content here", what do you exactly need? If you mean exactly at the bottom of the Div and not just after "Some content here", then you'll need to use position absolute as suggested by @dfsq.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical-align only works with two scenarios: inline-block or table-cell

```
.box:after {
     content: "";
     vertical-align: bottom;
     display: inline-block;
     height: 100%; /* also add this line of code to make it work*/
}
```

Comment: This solution does not place the `:after` pseudo element at the bottom of `.box`.

Comment: @hungerstar Oh! sorry, I forgot to mention the height for pseudo, please check updated answer and thanks for reminding me...

Comment: @hungerstar Maybe, it depends on OP's requirements. If we want to make  a footer with height less then 100%, this solution unlikely to work. http://jsfiddle.net/oc45nyux/5/

Comment: @dfsq - correct. This makes a "stretchy" footer that will go from the bottom of the `.box` element and stretch up to the content of `.box`, which may be a bit unpredictable. I up-voted your solution as that is what I would suggest and would have provided for an answer if you had not beat me to it.

Comment: `Vertical-align only works with two scenarios: inline-block or table-cell` including `inline` as well. However I don't recommend this method for vertical alignment purpose in this particular case. I'd rather go with @dfsq's solution.